# Meaning of "Military Cuts Our Specialty" in a barbershop window

Tags: meaning-in-context

A Navy man and new to town, I found a barbershop with a sign in the window that read "Military Cuts Our Specialty." I walked in and told the barber exactly what I wanted: "A standard Naval Aviator. Do you know what that is?"

I don't understand the meaning of "Military cuts our specialty".

Comment: It's not a sentence. There's no verb, just a garden-pathy 'cuts' which is actually a plural noun. Compare 'Picnic hampers our cup of tea.'

Comment: It's a sign in the window of a barber's shop, which -- like a newspaper headline -- needs to be read in context.

Comment: It means military haircuts are their specialty.

Answer (score 3):

The complete sentence should be: *"Military cuts **are** our specialty".* This means that the particular barber shop specializes in giving people haircuts of a military style.

So not this

http://www.film.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/top-gun_l1.jpg

but this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tqn.com](https://0.tqn.com/d/menshair/1/7/p/4/-/-/hightight.jpg))</sub>

Comment: If the barber was ex-military, it would explain the brevity. GI's being known to be terse and to the point with few words. And likely to expect everyone knows English well.

Answer (score 3):

To paraphrase 'Military Cuts Our Speciality' you could write

> We are very good at giving haircuts that conform to the
>   standards set out by the military

but you'd need a bigger sign in the window to fit all that on.

Comment: Window signs and headlines often follow similar conventions to pare the number of words. They are not intended to be grammatically correct sentences. (Of course, you said as much, but in a more humorous way.)

Answer (score 0):

They specialize in short military style haircuts, crew cut, flattop, H&T USMC